# Problem with scroll in ionic with firebase

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to scroll to the bottom when a view is a load, I try several things but no one work. sometimes he stops in middle for the screen, I think it because all messages ( 30 ) are not loaded.

HTML CODE:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let msg of messages; let last : last;">
        {{msg.message}}
        {{callLastItem(last)}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

TS

```
callLastItem(last){
if(last){
    this.content.scrollToBottom(1000);
}
}
// i try set timeout too
ionViewDidLoad(){
setTimeout(()=>{
this.content.scrollToBottom(1000);
}, 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i resolved it of this form: 
This is in the Constructor

```
this.fireservice.getLiveConversation()
.subscribe((conversacion: any) => 
{
    this.conversacion = conversacion;
     this.content.scrollToBottom();
});
```

Comment: like observable? just now i'm using promise, so probably i'm gonna change